# clearInterval won't clear the interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

This is pretty simple, you click a button to start a "setInterval", and click another button to stop it. The stop button does not work.

I realize there are lots of similar questions, but I thought I had already set things up like the answers stated to. How do I correctly clear the interval here?

Code:

```js
// declare globally
var runslides;

// set up play function
function startPlaying(){
 // set interval
 var runslides = setInterval(slides, 1000);
}

// function for set interval to use
function slides(){
 $('body').append('<div>Function Ran</div>');
}

// start the interval
$(document.body).on('click', '#start' ,function(event){
 startPlaying();
});

// stop the interval
$(document.body).on('click', '#stop' ,function(event){
 clearInterval(runslides);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  background:#222;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  background:#fff;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}

div {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#ccc;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <a href="#" id="start">Click To Start</a>
  <a href="#" id="stop">Click To Stop</a>
  <br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-declaring `var runslides = setInterval(slides, 1000);` locally just do:

```
runslides = setInterval(slides, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your use of `var` within the `startPlaying()` function - it redefines the scope of the `runslides` variable. You simply need to remove that.

```
function startPlaying() {
  runslides = setInterval(slides, 1000); // remove 'var' here
}
```

Better still, don't use a global variable in your JS code. You could place the reference of the timer in a `data` attribute on the `body` instead:

```js
function startPlaying() {
  $('body').data('slides-interval', setInterval(slides, 1000));
}

function slides() {
  $('body').append('<div>Function Ran</div>');
}

$('body')
  .on('click', '#start', startPlaying)
  .on('click', '#stop', function(event) {
    clearInterval($('body').data('slides-interval'));
  });
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #222;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  background: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="start">Click To Start</a>
<a href="#" id="stop">Click To Stop</a>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue of redefining `runslides` in function scope has been addressed in previous answers. Starting the slide show multiple times also needs to be prevented so as to make stop slides work conclusively.

E.G. initialize `runslides` for readability:

```
var runslides = 0;  // in global or outer function scope
```

change `startPlaying` to ignore clicks to start if the slideshow is running:

```
function startPlaying() {
    if(!runslides){
        runslides = setInterval(slides, 1000);
    }
}
```

and get the stop playing handler to clear the interval timer id:

```
// stop the interval
$(document.body).on('click', '#stop' ,function(event){
    if( runslides) {
        clearInterval(runslides);
        runslides = 0;
    }
});
```

(noting the test for `runslides` being truthy here is largely documentary:  `clearInterval` simply ignores invalid arguments).